# Problem with auto page break in iReport

Tags: pdf, grouping, ireport, subreport, page-break

I'm using iReport 3.7. I have a report with two subreports (order details and some selling statistics), and a grouping by seller.
One subreport is located  in the Detail band of the group, and the other one is in the group footer.

What's really odd is that no matter how long the report is, when I export it to PDF it's always one page long.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We got an option in the properties on report asking Ignore pagination. Just check that in order to avoid page-break.